# Better way to check a URL is not dead in PHP?

Tags: php, url

Currently, I'm using this code for detecting whether a link is dead or not:

```
function is_available($url, $timeout = 30) {
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $opts = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_NOBODY => true, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts); 
    curl_exec($ch); 
    $retval = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200; 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retval;
}
```

but this code is taking too much bandwidth. Is it possible to make it in such a ***way that it take less amount of bandwidth?***

Comment: Is the bandwidth the problem? I'd expect it's the execution time that's the biggest problem, which you can solve by checking the links with some task queue system so the users don't have to wait for a response for ages

Answer (score 2):

Use these to perform a `HEAD` request than only returns header, not response body, thus reducing bandwith:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
```